# react - using default export from import as a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have this code

```
import dataOption1 from './Option1.json'
import dataOption2 from './Option2.json'

async setParamsByDomain(optionUser) {
  await this.setState({ jsonName: "data"+ optionUser});
  console.log(this.state.jsonName )
}
```

its part of the code but the user gives 'Option1' or 'Option2' from list and its will use the right json.

how can I use it? Cause it uses as jsonName as a String and not as default export.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand the question - can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using await with setState?? setState does not return a promise so async/await won't do the work. To do something after state is updated you have to use callback function with setState like this:

```
this.setState(() => {
  jsonName: "data" + optionUser
}, () => console.log(this.state.jsonName))
```

Don't forget to upvote if i am right. :)

Comment: its print me the string dataOption1, but I want it to print the json that in file dataOption1 that I imported earlier

Comment: Try to parse the string into hain using JSON.parse(string) and then print.